# Accessing localhost via port on host machine within VirtualBox for testing IE compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, virtual-machine, port, virtualbox

I'm trying to access my localhost via a specific port in an XP VM (from modern.ie) supported by VirtualBox. I took the advice from numerous related articles I found before asking a new one here, restarting IE any and every time I changed something:

- **Change the hosts file (C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) to use my host machine's IP (192.168.56.1 localhost)** : this did not work (http://localhost:8056/), however accessing directly via IP http://192.168.56.1:8056
- **Use IP 10.0.2.2 for host machine** : same as above
- **Try with different Network settings, specifically "Bridged", in the VirtalBox settings** : fails

The project I'm trying to access also utilizes a CDN on a separate, localhost PORT that is hard-coded in a number of places, including the (local) app.config, otherwise I'd just use the IP itself.

I just wanted to point out, before it's brought up, that I am definitely using the full URL in IE8 (http://localhost:8056/); but, I won't discount that what I'm not understanding here is something simple-stupid like that :)